# How do I model the arms of a car axle as shown in the reference photos, as a single piece?

Tags: modeling, topology

I am trying to model the sides of a car axle, but I end up with ugly results and shading, no matter how I approach it. I could model it as seperate pieces, but the reference object is a single piece.

**My object:**
[image]

**My desired result:**
[image]
[image]

**Results I achieved by myself, but look far from the reference photos:**
[image]
[image]

**Result I have achieved thanks to the thread:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: [This might give you some guidance: Cutting Circular Holes in Curved Surfaces](https://topologyguides.com/circular-holes-curved-surfaces)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could begin with this kind of cylinders, and boolean. You need to avoid boolean when it's possible but this is typically a case where boolean is the best solution imho. The hard part is probably to guess how many vertices for each cylinder, 32 here is probably not good for the long one on X so I had to lower down to 16:

[image]

Then once booleaned begin to work a bit, <kbd>J</kbd> to join, <kbd>K</kbd> to knife, merge vertices with *Auto-Merge* and vertex *Snap* activated, etc. At one point you need to give your object a *Subdivision Surface* in order to test and modify the topology accordingly. Tris and ngons are acceptable as long as they don't create artefacts. Here (image below) it's not finished, just work in progress, it will need bevels on the edges, etc:

[image]

Comment: I have been trying to wrap my mind around cleaning the resulting topology from the boolean approach, and I have not been able to.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how I would begin to rework the topology once booleaned, it's not finished but I hope you get the thing

Comment: Thank you so much. I have made a notable progress thanks to your teachings. I will attach Images of my model so far to the main post.

Comment: glad I helped  ;)